# I do not have a FaceBook account but keep receiving emails

Tags: facebook, privacy

How do I stop people that I don't know emailing me to ask me to be their friend?

Why do the emails that I receive think that I will know a list of people that I have never heard of?

Comment: Just contact facebook like i did and request them to stop the emails, all the above will not help, as i have done them all without success. Using the unsubscribe at the end of an email will only do it for that request, you get hundreds....just think?

Answer (score 3):

There is an option on Facebook that scans the contents of a members' address book and sends out invites to people not already on Facebook. If someone has done this then you should have at least heard of them, having presumably exchanged e-mails at some point in the past.

Double check the links contained in the e-mail by examining the source (the option will vary depending on your e-mail client) - it could be a scam designed to get you to think you are signing up to Facebook as a means of getting personal details from you. It sounds like you've done the sensible thing so far and not clicked on any of the links.

Comment: Yes - my cousin asked originally but I ignored the request.  Now I have received other requests from people I don't know. I have asked to be unsubscribed by using the link at the end of the latest email.  Lets hope that puts a stop to it as I don't trust the security of Facebook.

Comment: I am still confused at the list of people that Facebook assumes I might know.

Comment: @user4680 - I've got a Facebook account and *I'm* confused by the people it suggests. If it told you why it's suggesting them (which it doesn't always do), I'd feel a whole lot happier.

Answer (score 0):

To stop being annoyed by the emails, set your email software or webapp to filter out any email coming from `*@facebookmail.com` and `*@facebook.com`.

As to why you are receiving them in the first place, ChrisF explained it very well.

---

Note that as facebook expand their email capabilities `*@facebook.com` addresses may become the source of *real* email messages.

Answer (score 0):

How to keep Facebook from emailing you? Click the unsubscribe link at the end of the emails.

I think you answered your own question when you said:

> I have asked to be unsubscribed by using the link at the end of the latest email. Lets hope that puts a stop to it…